# Missing helper file error after Rails3 conversion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activesupport

I'm in the midst of converting an old Rails2.3 project to 3, and I'm running into this runtime error when I load the first page:

```
Missing helper file helpers/activesupport.rb
```

[Full stacktrace here](https://gist.github.com/710992)

Has anyone else run into this? Looks like something changed in how helpers are loaded, but I don't see any obvious solutions.

I was able to work around the problem by created an empty file at `app/helpers/activesupport.rb` but I would like to know why this is happening in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a clash with ActiveSupport?

I am not sure why its even looking for such a helper - do you have a model or controller called activesupport?

Comment: No, it doesn't have anything to do with my code that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue with Hpricot. I had a `require 'hpricot'` statement in a helper, but I didn't have Hpricot in my Gemfile.

In your case, if you were explicitly requiring ActiveSupport somewhere, you would have to add it to your Gemfile (I just tried it and despite having Rails in my Gemfile, I still got the same error you were getting).